# How should I sanitize user input before passing it to %x (executing it)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am taking an input string from a user and using that as the parameters for a command line back-end program.

What is the best way to ensure that this input is "safe"? Aka they haven't inserted "; cd /; rm -rf" or some other ugliness into field?

Without any sanitizing I have...

```
@query = params[:query]
@result = %x( mycommand #{@query} )
```

I need to get the output of the command, so I can't use system("command","parameters") as that only returns true or false but would provide protection.

I know this is dangerous... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always, **always** define what you will accept and then deny everything else. Too often people try to allow everything and then deny the bad things.

1. Start with characters. I.e. if
   `mycommand` only needs alphanumeric
   input plus spaces then only allow
   that. There would be no chance of
   "`rm -rf /`" sneaking in, nor of the
   other 10,000 things that require
   punctuation.
2. Are there further
   syntactics/semantics of `mycommand`
   that you can use to define "good"
   input? Such as it requires exactly 2
   space separated parameters?

Without knowing what `mycommand` is I can't offer specifics, but you get the idea: don't try to throw away bad things; define valid and throw away everything else. Note that this is still hard, but without this approach it's almost impossible.

Comment: Ok. I guess I was wondering if there was a standard sanity checker... ala <%=h.

I can define the input. It is either a domain name or an IP address. So two regexps can cover those.

They will eliminate ;, \n, |, etc. So I will be set. I was just curious if there was a best practice way of "always run this filter" to use as a minimum.

Comment: SWR, there's no magic filter. Using %x with user input is too flexible for that. For domain name or address it would be much better to not use %x and directly call a library routine instead.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the nature of executing commands, I would probably say that you should use a whitelist to ensure that only anticipated commands are run. This strikes me as rather dangerous though!

Answer (score 1):

If as you said in your response to dwc, you require a domain name (im assuming you mean fully qualified) or an IP address, you can use Resolv to do a lookup on them and only accept them if there's a matching A/CNAME in the case of a domainname, or a PTR in the case of an IP.

If they enter an IP to which there's no reverse ptr, you could have problems. If they enter a domainname to which there's no A/CNAME, then chances are your command would have failed anyway.

Comment: you can use netaddr to validate IP addresses instead of resolv in the event there is no ptr. also u may wanna verify there's no ruby native way to implement mycommand.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if your commands are bounded, you could create a list in a drop down of commands and put the args into other fields/checkboxes/pulldowns.  Then validate each argument as Mike suggests.

This would prevent any user entered value from really making it to the command line.